# Displaying Array from Parse.com into ListView

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a class in my Parse database that looks like this:

[image]

I wan't to display it in a ListView in my activity so that it shows every Date and the Reps value, of the current device. For the device yhmrKgokfS it would look something like this:

> -Jul 05, 15
>   2/3
>
> -Jul 05, 15
>   5/3/2/4/2
>
> -Jul 05, 15
>   4/5/5/6/3

Here is the code that I'm using to achieve this:

```
    private ListView displayList;
    List<ParseObject> store = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        displayList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.displayList);


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Workout");
        query.whereEqualTo("Device", ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation());
        query.setLimit(100);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> dataList, ParseException e) {

                // logic here
                store = dataList;

            }
        });

        final ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ParseObject>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                store
        );

        displayList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
```

However, my list ends up being empty. What is the proper way of going about displaying the items from my Parse database into my ListView? I get the gist of it but can't properly execute it, can someone write some code to help me get what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `store` into your adapter but then you change it's reference in `done` of `findInBackground` which runs asynchronously so your adapter only holds on to the empty list.  You should modify the same instance of the `store`.  A quick fix would be to add to it in `done`

```
store.addAll(dataList)
```

and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Also the default adapter will only use `toString()` of each of your object so if you want to see anything useful, you will need to create a custom adapter.

Comment: How would I go about creating a custom adapter for my purpose?

Comment: Did the solution work for seeing data? Are you able to see the list being populated?

Comment: You can extend either base adapter or array adapter and override get view to set the fields in your list

Comment: The list is still empty. Where do I use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` ? I cant do it inside my done method as it is outside the scope.

Comment: Just initialize your array adapter before you query parse.

Comment: Tried it, list is still empty.

Comment: Is your query returning anything?  Try taking out where clause to make sure that you get something back

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the default `ArrayAdapter` knows how to interpret an `ArrayList<ParseObject>` object, you need to create your own adapter or use the default one with a `List<String>` object.

Also in the `done(....)` method, you should add the new items to the list instead of initializing the `store` object again.

```
 @Override
 public void done(List<ParseObject> dataList, ParseException e) {              
      store.addAll(dateList);
      context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
       });

 }
```

Comment: The symbol context cannot be resolved if I try this.

Comment: You have to create this variable, just add a `final Context context = this;` statement before the `findInBackground(...)` method.